# Python oauth() to access twitter, "No Module oauth"

Tags: python, api, twitter, oauth

I am trying to test oauth to access twitter using code from a course. I have a python script called twurl.py that holds this code (hidden holds the keys/tokens):

```
import urllib
import oauth
import hidden

def augment(url, parameters) :
secrets = hidden.oauth()
consumer = oauth.OAuthConsumer(secrets['consumer_key'], secrets['consumer_secret'])
token = oauth.OAuthToken(secrets['token_key'],secrets['token_secret'])

oauth_request = oauth.OAuthRequest.from_consumer_and_token(consumer, 
    token=token, http_method='GET', http_url=url, parameters=parameters)
oauth_request.sign_request(oauth.OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), consumer, token)
return oauth_request.to_url()
```

I am calling on the augment function in another script twtest.py:

```
import urllib
from twurl import augment 

url = augment('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json',
{'screen_name': 'user', 'count': '2'} )
print url
connection = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = connection.read()
print data
headers = connection.info().dict
print headers
```

I am running into this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/user/Desktop/python/twtest.py", line 7, in <module>
{'screen_name': 'user', 'count': '2'} )
File "/Users/user/Desktop/Python/twurl.py", line 6, in augment
secrets = hidden.oauth()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'oauth'
```

This code works in an online lecture I am using to learn. Oauth was pip installed by me and I can call the dir(oauth).

What am I missing, why is oauth  not being imported along with the twurl script? Even if I import oauth in twtest.py the same error occurs. 
Thanks!

EDIT:

Hidden module is a list of called variables:

```
 consumer_key = 'string'
 consumer_secret = 'string'
 token_key = 'string'
 token_secret = 'string'
```

Comment: Can you post the `hidden` module?  Of course feel free to leave out the actual passwords etc.

Comment: Sure, original post edited

Comment: I don't see anything named `oauth` in the `hidden` module.  Therefore, `hidden.oauth` is causing an error.

Comment: I edited hidden to import oauth and now I receive `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` in reference to hidden.oauth. Or are the keys/tokens to be in a function `def oauth():`?

Comment: Why does hidden even need to import oauth?  As far as I can see, hidden just declares some strings with values; it doesn't need to import anything.

Comment: Instead of declaring secrets, can you just use the items directly from the hidden module?  i.e. instead of `secrets['consumer_key']`, use `hidden.consumer_key`.

Comment: In any case, there's no way the original code worked if it looked like this.  You're missing something, or the lecture code was broken to begin with.

Comment: I was under the assumption hidden.oauth() was calling on the oauth module. If I run the twtest code with your suggestion 'hidden.consumer_key' ,etc. I recieve `NameError: global name 'oauth' is not defined`. I will have to review the lecture again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I find the solution in the book [*Python for Everybody](http://do1.dr-chuck.com/pythonlearn/EN_us/pythonlearn.pdf) page 167.

> For this next sample program we will download the files twurl.py,
>   hidden.py, oauth.py, and twitter1.py from [www.py4e.com/code](http://www.py4e.com/code) and
>   put them all in a folder on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I just came through the same problem (referring to hte twurl.py script from the Dr Chuck courses on python).

Everything worked fine when I put all the python scripts in the same folder as twurl.py (ad particularly oauth.py).

My understanding is that the twurl.py script required another script (oauth.py), and that installing new libraries (like oauth through pip installer) was not doing any changes.